# Process Injection and Process Isolation by OS

Tags: malware, windows, operating-systems, injection, memory

If the OS is responsible for ensuring that one process cannot access another process memory space, and the point of process isolation is to keep processes separate from one another, then how can a malicious process perform actions on another process, say for example a DLL injection?

Example: In the Windows API how can a malicious process call `CreateRemoteThread` on another process to create a malicious thread under that target process? Isn't that an inherently unsafe API call?

Comment: Unless a process restricts access to its memory using ACLs, you can generally access the memory of any process running under the same user as you. It's the same on linux.